# Ideal Diode Equation: Current Too Large

Tags: voltage, current, diodes

I'm having some trouble working with the Shockley's Ideal Diode Equation. I'm trying to generate a model plot for a 1N4001 type semiconductor diode, but the resulting graph seems incorrect.

```
Is (Reverse Saturation Current) = 5 * 10^-6 A
Vt (Thermal Voltage) = 25 * 10^-3 V
n (Ideality Factor) = 1

Id = Is * (e^(Vd/(n*Vt) - 1)
```

[image]

Nearly everything I've read states that the "Turn On" voltage should be closer to 0.7V. I'm inclined to believe that I'm doing something wrong. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your value for \$I_S\$ is way too high. Where did it come from?  Note that the ideality factor is usually closer to 2 for rectifier diodes.

Here is a typical [model](http://users.skynet.be/hugocoolens/spice/diodes/d1n4001.htm):-

.MODEL D1N4001 D IS=29.5E-9 RS=73.5E-3 N=1.96 CJO=34.6P VJ=0.627
+M=0.461 BV=60 IBV=10U

None of the numbers in the datasheet you [linked](http://www.diodes.com/datasheets/ds28002.pdf) are directly useful in determining \$I_S\$, however you could use this figure from the datasheet:

[image]

and play with different values of \$I_S\$ until you get reasonable agreement at lower current values. I say "lower current values" because real rectifier diodes have a resistive component to their \$V_F\$ which is more important at higher currents, and your ideal equation does not take that into account. Although \$I_S\$ is temperature-dependent, the figure specifies that it is measured with brief pulses of current, so we can assume that the \$T_J\$ is 25°C.

Comment: My value for Is came from the Data Sheet (http://www.diodes.com/datasheets/ds28002.pdf). I used the value specified as Peak Reverse Current at 25 Celsius (IRM). Perhaps I'm interpreting the datasheet incorrectly?

Comment: Okay, I see what happened. That's the guaranteed maximum value, which is much higher than the real typical value. I think there are other real mechanisms besides the theoretical \$I_S\$ that can add to the reverse leakage current.

Comment: How would I go about finding the typical reverse saturation current? I figured that would be the one listed on the data sheet so that people could generate these characteristic curves?

Comment: See my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks Spehro, that clears up a lot. I thought I was doing something terribly wrong.